# What's the Bug in this code ?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have initialized the root to NULL at the starting and the same will go to the first insert function. As i have sent the address of root, it should be changed, but its not, again in the second insert statement NULL vakue for root is going inside the insert function.

Please let me know, where I have missed it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct bst{
    struct bst *left;
    int data;
    struct bst *right;
}bst_t;

void insert(struct bst**, int);
void print(struct bst*);


int main() {
    struct bst *root;
    root = NULL;

    insert(&root, 45);
    insert(&root, 75);
    insert(&root, 5);
    insert(&root, 76);
    insert(&root, 25);
    insert(&root, 56);
    insert(&root, 89);
    insert(&root, 99);
    insert(&root, 98);

    print(root);

    printf("Print Any Char...\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void insert(struct bst **root, int num)
{
    struct bst *node = *root;

    if(node == NULL)
    {
        node = (struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst));
        node->left  = NULL;
        node->data  =   num;
        node->right = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(num < node->data)
        {
            insert(&(node->left), num);
        }
        else
        {
            insert(&(node->right), num);
        }
    }
    return;
}

void print(struct bst *root)
{
    struct bst *temp = root;

    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d --> ", temp->data);
        print(temp->left);
        print(temp->right);
    }
    else
    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to read this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Hint: Take a closer look at the code you execute to insert the first node into an empty tree. It's missing an assignment.

Comment: Hint2: avoid special cases. You only need to find (a pointer to) a NULL pointer and assign the new node to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a local copy of the root pointer:

```
struct bst *node = *root;
```

You then may modify it:

```
node = (struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst));
```

Unfortunately, you don't propagate this change back to the caller, and so the change is lost:(

Try:

```
*root=node;
```

at the end.

I strongly suspect that this is what @ Some programmer dude was hinting at in his comment:)